# how to send message?

Tags: c#, api, webmethod

Here `sendasync()` function is how to use I don't know.

I use `foreach` loop then get mobile number and message is same every time but main problem is SendAsync is how to use I don't know .

```
[WebMethod(true)]
public static string SendMessage(List<int> ids, string message)
{
    foreach (var id in ids)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        using (mapsEntityDataContext db = new mapsEntityDataContext())
        {
            tbl_inq edit = db.tbl_inqs.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Inq_Id == id);
            var mobile = edit.Contact;

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://sms.hspsms.com/sendSMS?username=hspdemo&message=" + message + "&sendername=HSPSMS&smstype=TRANS&numbers=" + mobile + "&apikey=66e12418-8b67-4c2a-9a08-4fd459bfa84c");
            client.SendAsync();
        }
        //client.SendAsync();
    }

    return "sucess";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to perform GET and POST requests:

Method A: `HttpClient`

Currently the preferred approach. Asynchronous. Ships with .NET 4.5; portable version for other platforms available via NuGet.

using `System.Net.Http;`
POST

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
   { "thing1", "hello" },
   { "thing2", "world" }
};

var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

var response = await client.PostAsync("http://www.example.com/recepticle.aspx", content);

var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

}

GET

```
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var responseString = await   client.GetStringAsync("http://www.example.com/recepticle.aspx");
}
```

Method B: 3rd-Party Libraries

RestSharp

Tried and tested library for interacting with REST APIs. Portable. Available via NuGet.

Flurl.Http

Newer library sporting a fluent API and testing helpers. HttpClient under the hood. Portable. Available via NuGet.

```
using Flurl.Http;
```

POST

```
var responseString = await "http://www.example.com/recepticle.aspx"
    .PostUrlEncodedAsync(new { thing1 = "hello", thing2 = "world" })
    .ReceiveString();
```

GET

```
var responseString = await "http://www.example.com/recepticle.aspx"
    .GetStringAsync();
```

Method C: Legacy

```
using System.Net;
using System.Text;  // for class Encoding
```

POST

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.example.com/recepticle.aspx");

var postData = "thing1=hello";
    postData += "&thing2=world";
var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;

using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

GET

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.example.com/recepticle.aspx");

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

Method D: WebClient (Also now legacy)

```
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
```

POST

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var values = new NameValueCollection();
    values["thing1"] = "hello";
    values["thing2"] = "world";

    var response = client.UploadValues("http://www.example.com/recepticle.aspx", values);

    var responseString = Encoding.Default.GetString(response);
}
```

GET

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var responseString = client.DownloadString("http://www.example.com/recepticle.aspx");
}
```